# Definir um valor default no DropDownListFor

Tags: c#

No form tenho um:

```
@f.FormGroup().DropDownListFor(r => r.AtividadeId, Model.AtividadeList).WidthLg(6)
```

que lista todos as atividades para realizar um filtro por atividade.

Quero colocar uma opção: "Listar Todos" para listar todas as atividades sem o filtro. 
Como eu coloco essa opção e ainda deixar como default?

No meu model coloquei:

```
[Display(Name = "Atividade")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
public String AtividadeId { get; set; }
public SelectList AtividadeList { get; set; }

public IList<RelAtividadeVM> Atividade { get; set; }
```

Comment: Acredito que essa seja sua resposta, dê uma olhada(em inglês): https://stackoverflow.com/a/23799134/3456409

Comment: Obrigado Marconcilio, mas no exemplo que você me enviou ele cria novas listas. Eu já tenho uma lista que vem do BD, com todas as atividades para serem filtradas, preciso adicionar um valor caso o usuário opte por emitir o relatório sem filtro.

Comment: @RafaelChristófano Se você tem uma propriedade `IList<RelAtividadeVM> Atividade` e a `SelectList AtividadeList`, que é a exibida na view... Siginifica que em algum momomento você está populando ela, e por isso basta iniciar ela com um item vazio e default....